# User input to list, without specified amount of iterations

Tags: python

EDIT - Apparently this is a duplicate. And while I've no doubt the core problems are answered elsewhere I think that the level is pretty blatant and thus the ability to comprehend other solutions and transpose them into my own problem is diminished. I searched before asking.

I'm just having a mess about and was trying to write a little thing with user input.

However, I'm not sure how to go about this without knowing how many iterations are needed, or having two questions?

I tried to modify it to take an if condition, which I don't really want anyway but that didn't work either :

```
for i in range(50):
    userIn = raw_input()
    urlList.append(userIn)
    print 'Continue? Y/N'
    ynAns = raw_input()
    if ynAns == 'n' or 'N':
        break
```

Basically I'm just trying to take user input to fill up a list and then print it out.

I also tried

```
import sys

listOne = []
num = int(raw_input('How many'))

for x in range(num):
    listOne.append(raw_input(('Entry #' + x+1 + ' '))


print listOne
```

pretty basic

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `ynAns` with both `'n'` and `'N'`:

```
if ynAns == 'n' or ynAns == 'N':
```

An alternative syntax:

```
if ynAns in ('n', 'N'):
```

---

The reason why your `if` statement doesn't work is that `ynAns == 'n'` and  `'N'` are two separate expressions.  `'N'` is always evaluated to `True`, so the `if` condition is always true.

Comment: cheers... I didn't think / realise that they worked like that. Nice one for the tips

Answer (score 1):

It's basically jh314's answer, but shorter:

```
if ynAns.lower() == 'n':
```

What it does is converts ynAns to lowercase, making your code more concise.

Comment: ...this isn't syntactically correct. Need `==` and `'n'`.

Comment: thanks! Yeah I goofed up that If !

Answer (score 1):

Dont use a `for` loop for this, you´re restricting your app to run within a limit of 50 iterations, instead use `while`:

```
userInput = None
userInput = raw_input("Enter input (N or n to stop): ")
while(userInput not in ['N', 'n']):
    urlList.append(userIn)
    userIn = raw_input("Enter input (N or n to stop): ")
```

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to use a for loop (because of the reasons you state...) I see how your's works though, I'm going to have a play with that, thanks